# Running LoopBack in the browser

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

The loopback documentation for [running Loopback in the browser](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Running+LoopBack+in+the+browser) seems to suggest that to get this running, create a file called `browswer-app.js` with the following code:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();
boot(app);
```

Then run browser on that file ...

```
browserify browser-app.js -o app.bundle.js
```

The end result is app.bundle.js which you can then use in an html file:

```
<script src="app.bundle.js"> </script> 
<script> 
  var app = require('loopback-app'); 
  var User = app.models.User;
  User.login({
    email: 'test@example.com',
    password: '12345'
  }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Login failed: ', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Logged in.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

When I do that, the `app.bundle.js` file that is created is **3 MB!**

That file is way to large to send to the broswer ... but it isn't clear to me what steps are wrong above. Please provide the concrete steps to be able to call Loopback models from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

For running HTML pages in browser
you only have to add HTML files inside "client" folder in loopback

and also remember to define the path in file middleware.json inside server folder

```
"files": {
    "loopback#static": {
    "params": "$!../client"
}}
```